# Is there a way to speed up python while loop without numpy or pypy or cython

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, while-loop

I'm trying to solve the USACO problem Censoring(Bronze), which was the 1st problem for the 2015 February contest. My solution works for some test cases, but then times out for the rest. How do I speed up the code? I tried to use Numba, but Numba doesn't work in USACO IDE. https://ide.usaco.guide/NXQs8hkV3sWOtNYsvyj
http://www.usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=526
This is the problem link.

This is my code:

```
input = open('censor.in', 'r').read().split('\n')
s = input[0]
c = input[1]
l = len(c)
while True:
    try:
        i = s.index(c)
        s = s[:i] + s[i + l:]
    except:
        break
output = open('censor.out', 'w')
output.write(s)
output.close()
```

It timed out for test cases 7-15.
I expected it to run with O(n) time complexity because of the while loop, which should work, but it didn't. What's wrong?

Comment: Any help is appreciated, i would accept any ideas

Comment: If your code runs without error and produces the correct result then you'll get better feedback on performance, style, technique if you repost your question over at the [Code Review StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not `O(n)` for two reasons.  To see why, let's consider what I think is the worst case:  The input is 500,000 `a`s followed by 499,999 `b`s.  And you're asked to delete `ab`.

Problem #1.  You are starting your search for the next occurrence of `ab` from the beginning of the string.  Each of your searches is going to be O(n), since you don't find `ab` until the middle of the string. If your previous search returned position `i`, you know that after collapsing the string, you don't need to go back further than `i - len(search_string) + 1`.  You would have found a result at `i - len(search_string)` on the previous round.

Problem #2.  String concatenation is O(n).  You are repeatedly chopping out the middle of the string and putting the front and back together again.  Again, you'll end up with an O(n^2) algorithm.  I can't come up immediately with a simple way to fix this. A more complicated solution would be to put the string into a `deque`, but that complicates the search part of the code.

In any case, your code is not O(n).  You have a single while loop, but you're doing more work than you realize inside each while loop.

Comment: Thank you. Can you give me some code?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a fix to the python code itself, but you can try closing other apps on your computer, particularly browsers as they take up alot of ram. Microsoft edge runs in the background, so you have to open up task manager (ctrl + shift + esc) and kill edge

Comment: it only helps a little. I quit everything except the one tab, and it still timed out.